# How can a UNIX process ignore system signals?

Tags: unix, process, signals

Every time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> inside the terminal a SIGINT signal is sent to the process. But what happens sometimes to the process and it is not responding to the signal?
Basically, I'm asking about how can a process ignore the signal theoretically?

Comment: Yes, if the application installs a handler for SIGINT and does nothing with it, nothing will happen when you press Ctrl-C.

Comment: Maybe a little naive of an answer, so I'm just submitting it as a comment in case it's relevant. In shell, simply add & to the end of any command line and it'll be executed asynchronously and ctrl+c won't have any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the exception of SIGKILL and SIGSTOP any process is free to install its own handler for any signal, which can respond however it likes (up to and including ignoring the signal completely).

Comment: Okay, I got it. But what do you mean by saying "install"?

Comment: @KonstantinosKonstantinidis http://stackoverflow.com/a/2485492/592139 sums it all up far better than I can.

Answer (score 4):

You should install signal handler. The simplest one is:

```
#include <signal.h>
...
/* Put this somewhere at the beginning of your code */
sigignore(SIGINT);
```

This will cause the specified signal (SIGINT) to be ignored. Alternatively, you can have some function called when signal occurs:

```
void function(int sig)
{
    // do something
}

// Somewhere at the beginning of your code put this...
sigset(SIGINT, function);
```

See details in corresponding manual pages. There are also more complex functions to manipulate signals, e.g. sigaction.