# How do I avoid terminating parent process with ctrl-c?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to write a shell in c and I want to implement the behavior of "cat > file" to then let me write into a file.

My main function:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t childPid;
    int status;
    char * cmdLine;
    int EXIT = 1;
    parseInfo info;
    int fd[2];
    char buffer[1024];

    char* env = getenv("USER");
    char cwd[BUFFER];

    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL) {
        perror("getcwd() error");
        return 1;
    }

    while (EXIT){
        printf("%s@%s > ",env,cwd);
        cmdLine = readline();
        info = parse(cmdLine);
        info.cwd = cwd;
        pipe(fd);
        childPid = fork();
        if (childPid == 0)
            {
                executeCommand(info,fd);
            }
        else
            {   
                close(fd[1]);
                if((read(fd[0], buffer, 1024 * sizeof(char))) == -1){
                    printf("Failed reading from pipe.\n");
                }
                    else{
                        if(!strcmp(info.cmd,"cd")){
                            strcpy(cwd,buffer);
                            chdir(buffer);
                        }       
                }   
                while (wait(&status) != childPid);  
            }
    }
}
```

the executeCommand:

```
void executeCommand(parseInfo info,int* fd){
    //print_info(info); // FOR DEBUGGING
    if(!strcmp(info.cmd,"cat")){

            cat(info);
        }
    else if(!strcmp(info.cmd,"cd")){
            info.cwd = changedir(info,info.cwd);
            if(write(fd[1], info.cwd, ((strlen(info.cwd)+1)* sizeof(char))) == -1)
                printf("Error while writing into pipe\n");

        }

    else if(execvp(info.cmd,info.args) == -1){
        printf("Error: unknown command [%s]\n",info.cmd);
    }
    exit(1);
}
```

Here's my cat function:

```
        void cat(parseInfo info){
    char* write_to_file = ">";
    char* append_to_file = ">>";
    if(!strcmp(info.args[1],write_to_file) || !strcmp(info.args[1],append_to_file)){
        if (info.args[2] == NULL){
            printf("unsupported sytax, file name expected.\n");
        }
        char* line;
        FILE* fp;
        if(!strcmp(info.args[1],write_to_file))
            fp = fopen(info.args[2],"w");
        if(!strcmp(info.args[1],append_to_file))
            fp = fopen(info.args[2],"a");
        while(1){
            line = readline();
            fputs(line,fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

How do I make ctrl-c not kill the parent process and just run fclose and kill the child only?
Or is there another method that's better here? 
I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485028/signal-handling-in-c

Comment: I do not see a parent and child process in your code. WHere is the *fork* and its management ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Signal Handling in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485028/signal-handling-in-c)

Comment: If it's written in C then it manifestly is not a shell script.  It looks like you may be trying to write a *shell*.  A shell script is pre-composed *input* to a shell.

Comment: Note that `cat` is normally an external program, not a shell built-in.  That doesn't mean that you can't provide it as a built-in, but you *do* have to decide where to draw the line between built-ins and external commands.  Me, I'd start by drawing it wherever makes the least work for me to implement all of the requirements.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to write a shell. Sorry for not being clear. Ill edit my post to include the rest of the code

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't mind calling the external cat, but then how do I implement redirection to support '>'?

Comment: @yevb, I/O redirection is a general shell behavior applicable to any command. It is in no way specific to use with `cat`, so it should not be a factor in your decision.  As to how to implement it, you should be able to find several prior Q&As about that here on SO.